# Ensure folder tree is complete before continuing

Tags: java, tree, watchservice

I am writing a hotfolder-type program where files+folders dragged into my designated upload folder are uploaded to a cloud service.

Quick overview of how I want to do this:

1. WatchService notifies me that something has been dragged into the folder.
2. Files.walkFileTree through the dragged folder, creating folders in the cloud service to emulate the dragged folder structure
3. Upload files i encounter to their respective folders.

My problem is I am having trouble finding the most robust way to ensure my nested directory tree has been completely copied to my watch folder. The walkFileTree method "snapshots" the directory tree immediately upon invocation, so it cannot detect folders created after it is called. This causes a problem because the very function I am using to detect changes won't see changes that happen after it is called.

To combat this, I have added a Thread.sleep(3000) before the walk, but that is so arbitrary and occasionally fails. Any ideas on how to tame this beast?

Is there a real-time file tree walker that doesn't set the tree structure at invocation? Am I doomed to write a custom function? (Joking, that sounds fun.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Create a simple checker to make sure the file tree is completely updated. Apache Commons' FileUtils has a sizeOfDirectory method that can return the size of a nested directory tree.

```
// makes sure system has folder tree completely updated
private void waitFoldersComplete(Path child) throws InterruptedException {
    long folderSize;
    do {
        folderSize = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(child.toFile());
        System.out.println(folderSize);
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } while(folderSize < FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(child.toFile()));
}
```

Hope that helps others in this situation.